# PHP namespace & use Fatal error class not found even when i already specified class with use

Tags: php, namespaces, fatal-error, classnotfound

I'm running into trouble with namespace in PHP. For an example I have a file like this

```
namespace App\Models\Abstracts;
abstract class Country{}
```

and then another file like this

```
namespace App\Models;

use App\Models\Abstracts\Country;

class City extends Country{}
```

I always get the

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class ... not found in ...

Can anyone help me?
thanks a lot.

Comment: Are the files containing those classes included? Are you using some autoloader? `use` doesn't include the actual file by itself, that needs to either be done manually, something like: `require_once '/path/to/Country.php';` or using some autoloader. The `use` is only to be able to reference the class name directly without needing to include the complete namespace every time. `extends Country` instead of `extends \App\Models\Abstracts\Contry`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To do that, I advise you to use the PSR (psr-4).

First, let's create a files structure as bellow :

[image]

Now let's init the composer to configure the psr-4.

jump to the root of the project (in this example the root directory of src), and run :

*you will be asked to fill some project information,  just skip it*

> composer init

A file named composer.json will be created in the root directory, let's configure the psr-4 inside.

```
{
    "name": "root/project",
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "src/"
        }
    }
}
```

Learn more about [psr-4](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/examples/)

to hover, we are just telling the PSR to point the name App to the directory src and then the name of subfolder should be the surname in your namespace.

**Example:**

```
App => src directory 
App\Models => src/Models directory
```

And so on

Next, you  should generate the autoload by

```
composer dump-autoload
```

The final project file structure seems to be something like :

[image]

I create a file called index.php in the root directory to test my code, but first, you should require the autoload which has been generated by the configuration we just did.

```
<?php  
  use App\Models\City;
  require __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';
  $city = new City();
  var_dump($city);
```

**Result:**

```
/var/www/myfm/index.php:9:
class App\Models\City#3 (0) {
}
```

I hope this helps you.