# Class not found in the namespace

Tags: php

I'm very new in the field and I'm trying to create my first composer package. I'm following the structure mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62486425/20282466) but for some reason I always get that the class is not found.

My directory structure is

```
Project
 - src/
   -- project
      index.php
 - vendor/
   -- composer/
   autoload.php
index.php
```

So in the main directory `Project` I have `index.php` with

```
<?php
use App\project;

// Autoload files using the Composer autoloader.
require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

$entry = new simplePrint();
echo($entry->printHome());
```

In the directory `src/project/` I have `index.php` with

```
<?php

namespace App\project;

class simplePrint {

    public function printHome() {
        return "Hey";
    }
}
```

in `composer.json`

```
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
                "App\\": "src/"
        }
    }
```

After I create the files, I've made

```
composer install 
composer dump-autoload
```

What I'm missing here?

Update: after `composer update` it is still same. The output of the composer update

```
$ composer update
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies
Nothing to modify in lock file
Installing dependencies from lock file (including require-dev)
Nothing to install, update or remove
Generating autoload files
```

> 127.0.0.1:45046 [500]: GET / - Uncaught Error: Class "App\project" not found in ...

Comment: try `composer update`

Comment: I have tried it. Nothing to install, update or remove. Updated in the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PSR-4 says following: The terminating class name corresponds to a file name ending in .php. The file name MUST match the case of the terminating class name.

So you must call your filename `simplePrint.php` and not `index.php`.

Here you can read some more information about PSR-4: https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/

Comment: Okay, I missed this. I've changed the filename inside the `src/project` from `index.php` to `simplePrint.php`. Still same error.

Comment: I have seen, that your use statement is wrong. Instead of `use App\project;` it must be `use App\project\simplePrint;`

Comment: That's it! ... along with the filename. Thanks!